# How to lock workstation in Xubuntu?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce

How to lock workstation in Xubuntu (XFCE, XFWM)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You use program called `xflock4`, I can really remember what is the shortcut to that bu i thing it is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>. Anyway if it doesn't work make sure it is installed.

Comment: Yes, Ctrl+Alt+Delete works. Thanks. And the keyboard shortcut can be chaned in XFCE keyboard configuration.

Comment: This doesn't work on XUbuntu 16.04 -- you can run xflock4 (it's installed), but it does nothing.

Comment: @ChrisDodd This answer was acceptable 6 years ago for a version of linux from back then, I can't maintain answers that are that old, especially where linux keeps updating/changing at least every year.

Comment: @ChrisDodd Check your keyboard shortcut settings. I have upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04 and have kept the same settings and Ctrl+Alt+Del still works for me.

Answer (score 2):

As of 16.04, there should be light-locker because of LightDM.  Use:

```
light-locker-command -l
```

to lock your workstation.

Comment: No need to apologize: for once, this is an actual answer not yet posted!  In the future however, refrain from using the words "try using" and use "use", "do", ..  if you're sure this'll work.

Answer (score 1):

I recently upgraded from Xubuntu 11.10 to Xubuntu 12.04 LTS, which made the `<Control><Alt>Delete` stop initiating the lock for some unknown reason.

To work around this (and reinstate the original behavior), you can go to Xfce Settings, then Keyboard, then Application Shortcuts.  You should find the original `<Control><Alt>Delete` shortcut for xflock4.  But now try adding a new shortcut for the same command (xflock4), by entering what you believe to be "Control", "Alt", "Delete".  The shortcut entered in will say `<Primary><Alt>Delete`.  Now the key sequence should work, but I don't know why my "Control" key is called "Primary".